# Rails & Devise: Require user to confirm email for specific functionality, but allow them to login before confirming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After a user signs up, I want to lead them to their dashboard. For full features they need to confirm their email.

Right now, when I add :confirmable to the User model, the user is unable to login.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. just write in **devise.rb**

   ```
   config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil
   ```
2. write an validation in **application.rb**

   ```
   def is_confirmed?
    if user_signed_in?
       if current_user.confirmed?
          return true
       else
          flash[:notice] = "You are not allow to view this page."
          redirect_to dashboard_path # your dashboard path
       end
    end
   end
   ```
3. use in your **contoller**

   ```
   before_action :is_confirmed?, except: [:dashbord]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with devise and [allowing-unconfirmed-access](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#allowing-unconfirmed-access)

Just add extreamely long period to allow them to login and then just check if the user has confirmed email — show them all dashboard content and vice versa.

Or you can just skip `:confirmable` validation at all.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this wiki page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

**# Solution 1**
Your can config in `devise.rb` something like:

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil
```

So it means user can access without any confirmation, but for instance:

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.hour
```

So they can access in 1 hour without confirmation

**# Solution 2**

```
# in User.rb
protected
def confirmation_required?
  false
end
```

So now use can access anything without confirmation but I think the solution #1 is more efficient!